# How do I get SQL results for the problem listed

Tags: sql

- id 1111 would be considered multi payor because of 03/18/2020 appt date
- id 2222 would be considered multi payor
- ID 3333 would be considered single payor

SAMPLE DATA

```
id      Apt         cp              dob
--------------------------------------------
1111    3/19/2020   BC/BS MEDICARE  00:00.0
1111    3/19/2020   MEDICARE        00:00.0
2222    3/18/2020   MEDICARE        00:00.0
2222    3/18/2020   BC/BS MEDICARE  00:00.0
2222    3/17/2020   BC/BS MEDICARE  00:00.0
2222    3/17/2020   BC/BS MEDICARE  00:00.0
3333    3/19/2020   BC/BS
3333    3/19/2020   BC/BS
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID,
    t1.dob,
    t1.CP,
    t1.apt,
    COUNT(*) AS Cpcount
INTO 
    t2l
FROM 
    t1
GROUP BY
    ID, dob, CP
```

I want to know if an ID, DOB and apt, have 1 CP on the same day or more than 1 CP (diff CPs) on the same day

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: Please tag DB as well

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need count of `distinct` CPs on a given date. Is it right? This solution is for Oracle and should work in other DBs.

```
select 
id, dob, apt, count(distinct(cp))
from table 
group by id, dob, apt
having count(distinct(cp))>1;
```

Comment: I'm trying to find id's that have more than 1 CP on the same day

Comment: `distinct` is not a function.